# Better way to make a bash script self-tracing?

Tags: bash, logging, trace

I have certain critical bash scripts that are invoked by code I don't control, and where I can't see their console output. I want a complete trace of what these scripts did for later analysis. To do this I want to make each script self-tracing. Here is what I am currently doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
# if last arg is not '_worker_', relaunch with stdout and stderr
# redirected to my log file...
if [[ "$BASH_ARGV" != "_worker_" ]]; then
    $0 "$@" _worker_ >>/some_log_file 2>&1  # add tee if console output wanted
    exit $?
fi
# rest of script follows...
```

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >>log_file 2>&1

echo Hello world
date
```

`exec` has a magic behavior regarding redirections: “If *command* is not specified, any  redirections take  effect  in  the current shell, and the return status is 0. If there is a redirection error, the return status is 1.”

Also, regarding your original solution, `exec "$0"` is better than `"$0"; exit $?`, because the former doesn't leave an extra shell process around until the subprocess exits.

Comment: Most excellent! I just knew there had to be a more elegant way. Thanks, Kevin; this will go into immediate use...

Comment: can it also output to current terminal and log to a file? I tried to use `tee` with `exec` but found no way..

Comment: I would like to link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself) where it is possible to see the output and also log it, all commanded from within the script!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for `set -x`?

Comment: @aaa: Yep, I know about "set -x" -- that's one of the things I occasionally make use of in the "# rest of script follows..." section above. I should have mentioned it; thanks for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

you may check a common open source trace library with support for bash.

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/utalm/
- http://www.unifiedsessionsmanager.org/en/downloads.html

The current available component is for scripting by bash, soon available are Python and C++. Additional going to follow are: Ruby, Java, JavaScript, SQL, PowerShell,...

The license is Apache-2.0

WKR
Arno-Can Uestuensoez